# .NET Core: Code Contracts approach is closed for now?

Tags: .net-core, code-contracts

Some years ago was many information about Code Contracts. I did not have time to learn it and found this time only now :)

But when I try to use it, I see, that Visual Studio 2017 does not support it, CC tool is updated last time more than 3 years ago...

So, Code Contracts is closed for now?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sadly, Code Contracts is no longer supported.

The good news is that C#8 is going to include a new [nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) feature that will handle a large portion of the invariants and pre- and post-conditions for which Code Contracts was used. This will assist with detecting and avoiding possible null-reference exceptions.

The bad news is that there is no built-in support for other types of contracts, and nothing like it has been announced for the future.

Correctness guarantees will have to come from third-party tools, or another language will have to be used (e.g., [Ada Spark](https://www.adacore.com/about-spark)).